# Xamarin SQLite-net & Linked issue (duplicate column name: objectId)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, sqlite-net, sqlite.net

I recently moved across to SQLite-net due to it supporting the new changes in Android 7.0 but it's bringing me major issues. I think it's related to linkers but not too sure how to handle the problem.

Firstly, if build my app in debug & release it works perfectly. No issues. If I then archive my app (Generate a signed APK) it starts to crash at different points depending on linker setting.

If I set my app to build with Sdk & user assemblies, my app instantly crashes. Here is part of the log:-

```
Caused by: android.runtime.JavaProxyThrowable: SQLite.SQLiteException: duplicate column name: objectId
                                                 at SQLite.SQLite3.Prepare2 (SQLitePCL.sqlite3 db, System.String query) [0x0001e] in <1096ddd2a2894a619279903f1fa07799>:0 
                                                 at SQLite.SQLiteCommand.Prepare () [0x00011] in <1096ddd2a2894a619279903f1fa07799>:0
```

If I set my app to use Sdk's only it works a little different. It actually starts the app, downloads half of the data. If I try to update the data by adding more it crashes. The app will then crash upon starting everytime until I delete the entire local storage for that app which it then works perfectly.

I have read about skipping linking assemblies too in which case I have skipped all of the SQL related libraries.

```
--linkskip=SQLite-net --linkskip=SQLite.NET --linkskip=SQLite.Net.Platform.XamarinAndroid --linkskip=SQLite.Net.Platform.XamarinAndroidN --linkskip=SQLiteNetExtensions --linkskip=SQLitePCLRaw.batteries_green --linkskip=SQLitePCLRaw.batteries_v2 --linkskip=SQLitePCLRaw.core --linkskip=SQLitePCLRaw.lib.e_sqlite3 --linkskip=SQLitePCLRaw.provider.e_sqlite3
```

Has anyone got any ideas on how to fix this issue. I wanted to release an app shortly but can't get around this. Very similar things are happening with my iOS app too which run on the same DB.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you find out which SQL language got the duplicate column error? You may selected two table with the same column name "objectId".

Comment: Thanks Mike. Not too sure what happened but I removed all references to every SQLite library I had and reinstalled them. The problem soon went away without any code changes. I also removed the skiplinks too. I think it might have been me referencing 2 seperate SQLite libraries that won't work together.

Comment: Since you solved the issue, please close the question. Thanks.

Comment: @jgoldberger I don't have enough points to close a question.

Comment: Alternately you can answer it and accept your own answer. Just takes it out of the search results when searching for questions without answers. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I found out what to do and how to over come this.

If you're experiencing this issue, it's most likely due that you're creating a table based off a model. Which is a smart thing to do in many cases. But note that this is using reflection. It's worthy to note in the github's FAQ:

> Because sqlite-net uses reflection, the MT linker doesn't recognize that it needs various properties. It then strips those properties off of the class.

https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net/wiki/FAQ

**So what now?**

You got two options as I see it.

*[Preserve] Attribute*

I'm not very experienced when it comes to this approach. In fact, I haven't really found good documentation to walk me through it. So I can't really comment on this.

*Writing Out Your Create Statements*

Simply by doing a

```
connection.Execute("create table .....");
```

This will allow you to create the tables without duplicate columns, and thus use the linker. Hooray!